# Advancing a bar progress according to the form_Load() function

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a progress bar in my window that I would like to advance during the Form1_Load() function

That is, at the beginning of this one it is at 0 and as we get to the end of this function I would like to know what progress is being made.

I tried this but the progress bar does not change the value of my progress bar according to the code but only at the end

```
    private void Window_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ///
        /// CHARGEMENT DE TOUTE LES MOTS 
        ///
        progressBarLoad.Value = 0;

        //Code...

        progressBarLoad.Value = 100; //end of the code

    }
```

Is that possible?

Thank you.

Comment: Load occurs before Shown, so the user see nothing... You may put the code in Shown event. or put the bar in a splash form that you create and show in the Load.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know the splash screen this will improve my program even if it remains the progress bar to set !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form `Load` event occurs before `Shown`, so the user will see nothing...

You may put the code in the `Shown` event.

Or you can put the bar in a splash form that you create and show in the Load.

To initialize the bar use `Step` property to define the increment and `Maximum` to define the number of steps.

Next use `PerformStep()` between steps with `Refresh`.

Example in the `Shown` event:

```
progressBarLoad.Value = 0;
progressBarLoad.Maximum = 5;
progressBarLoad.Step = 1;
progressBarLoad.Refresh();
Init1();
progressBarLoad.PerformStep();
progressBarLoad.Refresh();
Init2();
progressBarLoad.PerformStep();
progressBarLoad.Refresh();
Init3();
progressBarLoad.PerformStep();
progressBarLoad.Refresh();
Init4();
progressBarLoad.PerformStep();
progressBarLoad.Refresh();
Init5();
progressBarLoad.PerformStep();
progressBarLoad.Refresh();
```

Using a splash form, create for exemple a `FixedSingle` box with `ShowInTaskBar` false and `FormBorderStyle` false and `StartPosition` centerscreen. Put a bar with `Modifiers` as internal or public. So you can control it from the `Load` event:

```
var splash = new SplashForm();
splash.progressBarLoad.Value = 0;
splash.progressBarLoad.Maximum = 5;
splash.progressBarLoad.Step = 1;
splash.Show();
Init1();
splash.progressBarLoad.PerformStep();
splash.progressBarLoad.Refresh();
Init2();
splash.progressBarLoad.PerformStep();
splash.progressBarLoad.Refresh();
Init3();
splash.progressBarLoad.PerformStep();
splash.progressBarLoad.Refresh();
Init4();
splash.progressBarLoad.PerformStep();
splash.progressBarLoad.Refresh();
Init5();
splash.progressBarLoad.PerformStep();
splash.progressBarLoad.Refresh();
splash.Close();
```

You can refactor that using a `DoProgress` method:

```
void DoProgress()
{
  splash.progressBarLoad.PerformStep();
  splash.progressBarLoad.Refresh();
}
```

So you may also put this method in the `SplashForm` (remove `splash.`) and add a `InitProgress`:

```
public void InitProgress(int stepCount, int stepIncrement)
{
  progressBarLoad.Value = 0;
  progressBarLoad.Maximum = stepCount;
  progressBarLoad.Step = stepIncrement;
}
```

Therefore you cas do this now:

```
var splash = new SplashForm();
splash.InitProgress(5, 1);
splash.Show();
Init1();
splash.DoProgress();
Init2();
splash.DoProgress();
Init3();
splash.DoProgress();
Init4();
splash.DoProgress();
Init5();
splash.DoProgress();
splash.Close();
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
I found a tuto for the splash screen you save my life!